# Is $y = \lim_{n \to 0} \left( x \bmod n \right)$ the same as $y = 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, elementary-number-theory, continuity, modular-arithmetic

My question is simply whether or not

$$
y = \lim_{n \to 0} \left( x \bmod n \right)
$$

is identical to

$$
y = 0.
$$

I don't have a formal education in either number theory or analysis, so I'm not sure if it is possible for a discontinuous function to approach a continuous function.

Comment: What is your meaning of $x\mod n$ in this context?  Are you using it as a function that returns very specifically the number $r$ such that $0\leq r<n$ and there existing a number $q$ such that $x=qn+r$?  That may be what programmers use "mod n" to mean frequently, but in maths we more often use it to refer to equivalence classes of numbers, not individual numbers.

Comment: I think $x \bmod n$ in this context can be defined as $x - n \left \lfloor \frac{x}{n} \right \rfloor$.

Comment: "*I'm not sure if it is possible for a discontinuous function to approach a continuous function*"  Of course it can... there are plenty of examples.  A simpler example would be $f_n(x) = \begin{cases}\frac{1}{n}&\text{if }x\geq 0\\ -\frac{1}{n}&\text{if }x<0\end{cases}$.  It should be obvious that $f_n(x)$ converges pointwise to $0$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Similarly, it is possible for a sequence of continuous functions to approach a discontinuous one.  For example $f_n(x)=\begin{cases}0&\text{if }x\leq 0\\ nx&\text{if }0<x\leq\frac{1}{n}\\1&\text{if }x>\frac{1}{n}\end{cases}$.  Properties held by elements in a sequence do not need to be shared by the limit of the sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answered here for completeness, so this question does not remain unanswered.

If you define $y=x \pmod n = x-n\big\lfloor \frac{x}{n} \big\rfloor$, then indeed, this function is well-defined for real $x$ and any real positive $n$ [even though convention typically has $n$ to be integral], and $\lim_{n \rightarrow 0}x \pmod n = 0$. Indeed, $x \pmod n$ takes on, for all $x$, the values in $[0, n)$ and does not take on any values larger than $n$ nor less than $0$.

In fact, if you were to graph $x \pmod n$ as a function of $x$, you would get a sawtooth function https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sawtooth_wave [click the link to see the type of graph I am referring to, the function graphed resembles the the teeth of a saw]. For each integral $k$, the function is increasing in $x$ for $x$ in the interval $[\frac{k-1}{n}, \frac{k}{n})$, and on that interval. Then, put informally, the function approaches the point of a "tooth" of the saw [the point $(x=\frac{k}{n},y=n)$] as $x$ approaches $\frac{k}{n}$ from the left, and gets arbitrarily close but does not reach. But then for $x =\frac{k}{n}$ itself, note that $x \pmod n$ is $0$, so the function is back in the deepest part of the valley between the saw teeth, at $(x=\frac{k}{n},y=n)$.

The smaller $n$ is, the finer the sawteeth become i.e., the closer the graph stays to the $x$-axis.